# Selecting first failure from truth table c#

Tags: c#, datatable, datacolumn, truthtable

I have a datatable with 4 columns of data, the first with limit values and the next 3 with the maximum values (of a different table). I need to run a truth table that will find the first value which fails limval > maxval. Then I need to output the maxval column name and limit value which it failed at. This is how I've done the truth table so far.

```
dtTruth = new DataTable();
        dtTruth.Columns.Add("Truth", typeof(double));

        double truthval;

        for (int i = 0; i < dtLimits.Rows.Count; ++i)
        {
            truthval = 0;
            if ((Convert.ToDouble(dtP2P.Rows[i]["Limits"]) > (Convert.ToDouble(dtP2P.Rows[i]["MaxVal1"]))))
            {
                truthval = 1;       //pass -> not out of bounds
            }
            else
            {
                truthval = 2;       //fails -> well parameter is out of bounds
            }
            dtTruth.Rows.Add();
            dtTruth.Rows[i]["Truth"] = truthval;
        }
    }
```

I need to export the column name and limit value where the first 2 occurs
Open to any and all suggestions of how to do this (or change how i've done the truth table)
Thanks!

Comment: Note code is for just the first column in the truth table, there will be 3 columns

Comment: I don't understand your question - if you have any. Could you please explain in more detail what problem you have?